November 2012: How to keep our answer rate above 80%?
I've just been noticing our site statistics over the last month or so. 
The good news is that "questions per day" have improved in recent weeks and our visits per day have improved quite a bit also.
The slight concern is that our answer rate has dropped a little. For many months we've had an answer rate around 83% but at time of posting it is around 80%. Get below 80% and we're in the "red".
Are there any strategies we could adopt to boost our answer rate?
November 10th 2012 Site Statistics

June 2012 Site Statistics
For reference, here are our some statistics from around June:


A few suggestions:
1) Take a look at the list of Unanswered Questions, and see if you can answer any of them. Older questions will slip off the front page, and you may have an answer for a few questions that you haven't seen before.
2) While you're looking through the questions, feel free to flag any question you think should be closed. This may be because the question is off-topic, or perhaps it's on topic but too broad, too subjective, or do not show enough prior research. I imagine there are a few questions out there that we've tried to reword but still haven't gained any traction. If there are questions that are still not in workable form, and have since been ignored, we should close them.
3) Some questions are overly specific. They ask about an effect that has never been tested before. This doesn't mean the question is unanswerable. If you know the topic pretty well, it's all right to answer "We don't know", as long as you elaborate on the question and highlight some relevant studies.

Great suggestions. I'd like to add to #1, if you can;d answer it, share it! I post questions to facebook often. Can't say it's done any good, but I'm trying :-)

@Josh Great suggestion, and that should also help us with 'visits per day'!

I should be able to upvote this more than once!
